# popbio stochastic function modification in r

Tags: r, loops, matrix, matrix-multiplication, popbio

Anyway to modify the following functions contained with the `popbio` package in r in the following ways:

1.) stoch.projection():
a.) sample from the list of transition matrices sequentially
b.) in addition to tmax, show the final pop projections for all years leading up to tmax (still preserving the nreps iterations for each projected year)

2.) stoch.growth.rate():
a.) sample from the list of transition matrices sequentially. Repeat sequence in order if maxt exceeds number of transition matrices in the list.

3.) stoch.quasi.ext():
a.) sample from the list of transition matrices sequentially. Again repeat sequence where applicable if nreps exceeds number of transition matrices in the list

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this. While I have created functions to allow sampling with out replacement and made some tweaks outside of the package, I imagine this would be easier to do within the framework of the package and will allow for added sampling flexibility.